# Cómo pasar al stage las modificaciones que están en una carpeta específica

Tags: git

Tengo un proyecto con muchas subcarpetas pero quiero pasar al `stage` sólo todos los cambios que están en una carpeta especifica.

Al hacer git add. se pasa al `stage` todos los cambios y los que busco, es una forma de hacer algo como esto git add nombreCarpeta.

Comment: Exactamente lo que dices: `git add directorio/`. Pruébalo!

Comment: Y si quieres añadir **solo los cambios**, usa la opción `-u`. De otro modo añadirás también todos los ficheros nuevos que hubiera en esa carpeta (salvo los que estuvieran exceptuados en el `.gitignore`)